# Lookup query parameters in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, query-string

I just initialized a Yesod project (no database) using `yesod init`.

My `HomeR` GET handler looks like this:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    let submission = Nothing :: Maybe (FileInfo, Text)
        handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
    defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

When using `yesod devel`, I can access the default homepage at `http://localhost:3000/`.

How can I modify the handler listed above to retrieve (and display) a HTTP GET query parameter like `id=abc123` when accessing this URL:

`http://localhost:3000/?id=abc123`

**Note:** This question was answered Q&A-style and therefore intentionally doesn't show research effort!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll show two different methods to achieve this. For both, you'll need to add this code to your template, e.g. in `homepage.hamlet`:

Note that it is not guaranteed there is any `id` parameter present when accessing the URL, therefore the type resulting from both methods is `Maybe Text`. See [the Shakespearean template docs](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates) for a detailed explanation of the template parameters.

**Method 1: lookupGetParam**

The easiest way you can do this is using [`lookupGetParam`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:lookupGetParam) like this:

```haskell
idValueMaybe <- lookupGetParam "id"
```

When using the default setting as generated by `yesod init`, `idValueMaybe` needs to be defined in both `getHomeR` and `postHomeR` if `idValueMaybe` is used in the template.

Your `HomeR` GET handler could look like this:

```haskell
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    idValueMaybe <- lookupGetParam "id"
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    let submission = Nothing :: Maybe (FileInfo, Text)
        handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
    defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

**Method 2: reqGetParams**

Instead of looking up the query parameters by name, you can also retrieve a list of query key/value pairs using `reqGetParams`. This can be advantageous in certain situations, e.g. if you don't know all possible keys in advance. Using the standard [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function you can easily lookup a certain key in that list.

The relevant part of your code could look like this:

```
getParameters <- reqGetParams <$> getRequest
let idValueMaybe = lookup "id" getParameters :: Maybe Text
```

Your `getHomeR` could look like this:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    getParameters <- reqGetParams <$> getRequest
    let idValueMaybe = lookup "id" getParameters :: Maybe Text
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    let submission = Nothing :: Maybe (FileInfo, Text)
        handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
    defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

Comment: how to use the second method with a POST method request?